# Change display of floating point values in debugger

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

When I debug in Slime and inspect the value of a floating point variable, I see something like

```
6.8998337e-4
```

However, I find that very hard to read and would prefer

```
0.00068998337
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What Lisp dialect/implementation? Check its documentation to see if there's a way to customize how values are shown in the debugger.

Comment: Given that he uses the SLIME debugger, I would first think that the value display has to be customized there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~F" 6.8998337e-4)
"0.00068998337"
CL-USER> (format nil "~E" 6.8998337e-4)
"6.8998337e-4"
```

In slime/sly, when you Inspect (C-c I) the value 6.8998337e-4, you get:

```
#<SINGLE-FLOAT {3A34E00000000019}>
--------------------
Scientific: 6.8998337e-4
Decoded: 1.0 * 0.70654297 * 2^-10
Digits: 24
Precision: 24
```

The "Scientific" value is formatted in swank/slynk in [contrib/swank-fancy-inspector.lisp](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/slime/slime/-/blob/contrib/swank-fancy-inspector.lisp?L941-961) or [contrib/slynk-fancy-inspector.lisp](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/joaotavora/sly/-/blob/contrib/slynk-fancy-inspector.lisp?L965-985) :

```
(defmethod emacs-inspect ((f float))
  (cond
    ((float-nan-p f)
     ;; try NaN first because the next tests may perform operations
     ;; that are undefined for NaNs.
     (list "Not a Number."))
    ((not (float-infinity-p f))
     (multiple-value-bind (significand exponent sign) (decode-float f)
       (append
    `("Scientific: " ,(format nil "~E" f) (:newline)
             "Decoded: "
             (:value ,sign) " * "
             (:value ,significand) " * "
             (:value ,(float-radix f)) "^"
             (:value ,exponent) (:newline))
    (label-value-line "Digits" (float-digits f))
    (label-value-line "Precision" (float-precision f)))))
    ((> f 0)
     (list "Positive infinity."))
    ((< f 0)
     (list "Negative infinity."))))
```

You could modify emacs-inspect method and change `(format nil "~E" f)` to `(format nil "~F" f)`, or you could shadow emacs-inspect with an **emacs-inspect :around method** to modify the behavior to use "~F".